# android - How to clear TextinputLayout's error color?

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

I am using android design library's TextinputLayout on two page "Signup" and "Login". I have a problem about its control. I couldn't control inputLayout's setError method. When I call setError("error_string"), EditText's bottom line color gets changed to red and the error appears on the SignUp Page. This is the behaviour that I expect and back to onBoard and Now I open the Login activity and I can see that the bottom line for all EditText fields inside in my application.This is not always reproducible, but if I keep trying, I can eventually get it.

Update: I solve this problem that TextInputLayout setErrorEnabled(false) and EditText SetError(null) on backpress event or change activity.
**My app screens part of error.**
[Signup Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMQgX.png)
[Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBFbd.png)

Comment: Hi. Have you found any way to solve this issue? Gokhan.

Comment: Please post your style for `TextInputLayout`